# how to use row_count() with transAction?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, transactions, rowcount

i have an stored procedure in mysql like below:

```
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;  
    INSERT INTO tbl1 (v1,v2) VALUES (p1,p2);
    UPDATE tbl2 SET s1 = 1 WHERE s2 = s3;
    SELECT ROW_COUNT();
COMMIT
END
```

in this query even the transaction doesn't commit, the row_count will be 1.
in fact my question is that how can i use row_count that it returns 0 if rollback occurred?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into a similar problem recently, but I managed to solve it by selecting the row count inside of the transaction block and then returning it after the commit:

```
BEGIN
START TRANSACTION;  
    INSERT INTO tbl1 (v1,v2) VALUES (p1,p2);
    UPDATE tbl2 SET s1 = 1 WHERE s2 = s3;
    SET @rowCount = (SELECT ROW_COUNT());
COMMIT
SELECT @rowCount;
END
```

I don't know if this is the best way to solve it, but it seems to work for me :-)

Comment: tnx for your answer, it's the right way that i used it too that time, anyway thanks again.